# Conditions for a dynamical system to be input-commutative?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

Consider an explicit discrete-time dynamical system (recurrence relation),
$$
x_{t+1} = f(x_t, u_t)\ \ \ \ \forall t \in \mathbb{N}
$$
where $u$ is an exogenous sequence of "inputs." I am intrigued by systems for which the value of $x_t$ is **invariant to permutations of the input sequence** up to time $t-1$. That is, if we write the "solution" to the system as,
$$
x_t = g(x_0,u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_{t-1})
$$
then I define the property "input-commutativity" as when $g$ is commutative in the arguments $u_0,u_1,...,u_{t-1}$. Put simply, it means that the system ends up in the same state regardless of the order that the inputs are provided in.

Here are some simple examples on $\mathbb{R}$:
\begin{align*}
x_{t+1} = x_t u_t\ \  &\implies\ \ x_t = x_0\prod_{\tau=0}^{t-1}u_\tau \tag{1}\\[6pt]
x_{t+1} = \max\{x_t,u_t\}\ \  &\implies\ \ x_t = \max\{x_0,u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_{t-1}\} \tag{2}\\[6pt]
x_{t+1} = x_t + 2u_t\ \  &\implies\ \ x_t = x_0 + 2\sum_{\tau=0}^{t-1}u_\tau \tag{3}
\end{align*}

The first two examples show that $f$ need not be linear and the third example shows that $f$ need not itself be commutative. Meanwhile, $x_{t+1} = 2x_t + 2u_t$ is an example of a linear and commutative $f$ that does **not** yield an input-commutative solution. It seems that linearity and/or commutativity of $f$ have no bearing on whether the solution will be input-commutative.

A perhaps motivating example is the recursive application of Bayes rule from probability theory. If $u$ is a sequence of independent random variables then we can define the "belief state" for some random variable $\theta$ as $\ x_t = p(\theta|u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_{t-1})\ $ and have,
$$
x_{t+1} = \frac{p(u_t|\theta) x_t}{p(u_t)}\ \  \implies\ \ x_t = x_0\prod_{\tau=0}^{t-1}\frac{p(u_\tau|\theta)}{p(u_\tau)}
$$

Though this is just a glorified version of the $x_t u_t$ example (1), it provides the nice physical interpretation that one's belief about an unknown parameter should end up the same no matter what *order* the evidence is provided in. (For what it's worth, the $\max(x_t,u_t)$ example (2) also has an interpretation as a "peak detector" device, and the additive example (3) could represent work/transactions performed on a storage of energy/money).

Anyway, the only general form for a solution $g$ in terms of the dynamic $f$ is,
$$
g(x_0,u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_{t-1}) = f(f(f(f(x_0,u_0),u_1),\ldots),u_{t-1})
$$
from which it is not so obvious to see what about $f$ is necessary and/or sufficient to make $g$ commutative in $u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_{t-1}$.

My questions are:

1. Can this property of the solution $g$ be deduced by any properties of the dynamic $f$?
2. Does this property have an official name? Any references for its study?
3. Is there a formalization of this concept for continuous-time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you were dealing with a continuous-time control system on a manifold, where the evolution equation was given by $\dot x_t = f(x_t, u_t)$ for a time-dependent vector field $f(-, u_t)$, I believe it can be shown that your behavior is "permutation-invariant in the control," meaning that any control with the same integral gives the same system flow, if and only if the vector fields that $f(-, u_t)$ takes at Lebesgue points commute pairwise, in the sense that their Lie brackets vanish. That seems like a satisfactory condition. We would call the control system "commutative".

Comment: In your case, of course things also simplify if the family $f(-, u_t)$ of maps you get for $t = 1, \ldots, n$ are commutative bijections of the phase space. Is your question specifically about the case where these maps are not bijections?

Comment: @ChristopherGadzinski My question is about any conditions on $f$ from which we can deduce that the system is "permutation-invariant in the control." What exactly do you mean by $f$ being a "commutative bijection" of the phase-space? Is $x_{t+1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_t + u_t)$ a commutative bijection? It does not yield trajectories that are invariant to control permutations. Interestingly, $x_{t+1} = x_t + u_t$ does.

Comment: I mean, bijections that commute with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one straightforward condition under which the value of $x_t$ is invariant under permutations of the input sequence.

First, let's make some definitions. Let $X$ be the phase space of your system and $U$ the control space, so that $f$ is a function from $X \times U$ to $X$. For every element $u \in U$, let $f_u \colon X \to X$ be the "partial application" $f_u(x) = f(x, u).$ We will call our control system "commutative" when the $f_u$ commute pairwise, meaning that $f_u \circ f_v = f_v \circ f_u$ for all $u, v \in U$.

Then, the function $x_t = g(x_0, u_0, \ldots, u_{t - 1})$ is invariant under permutation of its last $t$ arguments whenever our control system is commutative. Furthermore, if every map $f_u$ is a bijection and the permutation-invariance condition of $g$ holds *for every* tuple $(x_0, u_0, \ldots, u_{t - 1})$ for some fixed $t > 1$, then the control system is commutative.

We can use this criterion to investigate the two examples you gave in your response to my earlier comment. When $f(x, t) = \frac 1 2 (x + u)$, the maps $f_u$ are bijections but do not commute, since
$$(f_u \circ f_v)(x) = \frac 1 2 \left ( \frac 1 2 (x + v) + u \right) = \frac 1 4 x + \frac 1 4 v + \frac 1 2 u.$$
We conclude that permutation-invariance fails. On the other hand, the map $f(x, u) = x + u$ makes
$$(f_u \circ f_v)(x) = x + u + v = (f_v \circ f_u)(x),$$
so in this case permutation-invariance holds.

As far as directions for future study, I can see two connections. First: if your maps $f_u$ are bijections, then the problem of reaching a given $x_t$ from a given $x_0$ in minimal time can be formulated as a problem from group theory. If your control system is also "commutative" in the above sense, then the underlying group of study is Abelian, which simplifies the question a lot. To understand why, it's useful to know some facts about Abelian groups.

Second: if your equation $x_{t + 1} = f(x_t, u_t)$ is replaced by a continuous-time differential equation
$$\dot x_t = f(x_t, u_t)$$
and the partial applications $f_u$ are smooth vector fields, then there is an analogous (but somewhat more complicated) notion of a "commutative" interaction between the vector fields $f_u$: the Lie brackets $[f_u, f_v]$ should vanish. In these conditions, it will be true (subject to some technical conditions) that $x_t$ depends only on $x_0$ and on the *integral* $\int_0^t f_{u_\tau} \, d \tau$ of the controlling vector field.

To explain why I'm being picky about bijections in my criterion above, let's also give an example situation where the family of functions $f_u$ do *not* commute, but nevertheless where $x_t$ does not depend on the order of the controls $u_0, \ldots, u_{t - 1}$ for $t = 3$.

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3 \} \times \mathbb{N}$ and $U = \mathbb{N}$. Define
$$f((x_1, x_2), u) = \begin{cases}
(x_1 + 1, \frac 1 2 (x + u)) & : \text{if $x_1 < 3$} \\
(3, 1) & : \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Then, we can check that $(f_u \circ f_v)(1, x) = \left (3, \frac 1 4 x + \frac 1 4 v + \frac 1 2 u \right)$, so the functions $f_u$ do not commute. However, any composition $f_{u} \circ f_{v} \circ f_{w}$ will take the constant value $(3, 1)$, so we will have the input commutativity condition when $t = 3$.

Comment: Thanks! Much simpler in retrospect. Just one question: why do you mention the bijection detail? For example $f_u(x) = \max(x,u)$ is not a bijection but does commute $\max\big{(}\max(x,u),v\big{)} = \max\big{(}\max(x,v),u\big{)}$. What role does bijectivity (or lack of it) play in the overall input commutivity of the solution?

Comment: @jnez71 I've edited my answer with an example situation where the functions $f_u$ are not bijections and they do not pairwise commute, but we do have input-commutativity with $t = 3$.

Comment: I see. So $f_u \circ f_v = f_v \circ f_u$ and $f$ bijective together are *sufficient* for input-commutivity (at all $t$), but bijectivity isn't always *necessary* as the $\max$ example shows, and $f_u \circ f_v = f_v \circ f_u$ alone isn't always sufficient as your last example shows... Well, maybe not. It seems your last example just shows how lack of bijectivity can be used to make a non-commutative $f_u$ yield a commutative solution for just one time, whereas I am only interested in solutions being input-commutative at all times (and initial states). Perhaps then bijectivity is unnecessary.